# How to add new column where the value is from query (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have query that split varchar of string and number and only return the number. Is it possible to save result from this Query into a new column on the same table? And I want it to be permanent, meaning if I close and open the database, the result will still be there without I run the query anymore.

Edit :

I want a permanent column that I can modify and interact to.
For context, I basically have two Tables, Table1(ColumnA,ColumnB) and Table2(ColumnX,ColumnY).

ColumnA is a varchar and the value is a modified value of ColumnX(PK of Table2), so I want to extract only the integer value form ColumnA, so I can make relation between Table1 and Table2.

Example :

```
Table1
    ColumnA | ColumnB
    ----------------
    1234ab  | text1
    2345cd  | text2
    456aaa  | text3

Table2
    ColumnX
    1234
    2345
    456
```

The Query : `select REGEXP_SUBSTR(ColumnA,"[0-9]+") as ColumnC from Table1;`

Query Result :

```
ColumnC
---------
1234
2345
456
```

Expected Result :

```
Table1
    ColumnA | ColumnB | ColumnC(FK)
    ----------------------------
    1234ab  | text1   | 1234
    2345cd  | text2   | 2345
    456aaa  | text3   | 456

Table2
ColumnX(PK)
1234
2345
456
```

I've tried to do this `UPDATE tablename SET ColumnC = REGEXP_SUBSTR(ColumnA,"[0-9]+");` but it return this error :

```
Unhandled event loop exception
java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

Comment: Simple answer is, yes of course

Comment: The current error message doesn't stem from the DB, but from java apllication layer. Can you please share the one stems from the DB layer, if exists any?

Comment: As I assume you are only going to do this once, why not do it in phpMyAdmin or Workbench or even the command line in a terminal and remove the necessity for java

Comment: *Is it possible to save result from this Query into a new column on the same table?* You must add this column into the table structure firstly, then update with another query. Or simply create generated column.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I actually use dBeaver for this. I run the update query above, it return those error and actually force close dbeaver.

Comment: @Akina I tried the former, I add ColumnC into the table first, the run update set query, but it return the above error.

Comment: The query is correct, you receive java error. Maybe you use incorrect method for to execute the query which does not produce the output rowset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `ColumnC` to reflect changes in `ColumnA` you could use a calculated column:

```
alter table t 
  add column ColumnC varchar(20) as (REGEXP_SUBSTR(ColumnA,'[0-9]+'));
```

[Example fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d06d4cbe99a721e727c81ab6715f1277)

Comment: This kinda worked, but not exactly what I'm searching for since I can't interact with the Column. I want to assign ColumnC as a FK. (Basically, ColumnA is modified version of table2 PK as varchar. So I want to take integer value of varchar ColumnA and then assign it to ColumnC so I can make relation between Table1 and Table2.)

Comment: You didn't mention this requirement but to my knowledge you can't use a generated column as a foreign key (not sure if adding `stored` affects that), you might need to consider a normal column updated using a trigger.

Comment: Yes, my bad, I'll edit the question to make it more clear. Can you explain more about trigger? I tried to add the new column on the table first, then use update on it but as you can see from my question, it return some error.

Comment: @AbbiKRK The error in your question is not coming from the database, updating the column [works fine](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=46afccc232fbd69258aa21fb8c119396)

Comment: How can It suddenly works now?!  Is it because I use " instead of ' like you did? either way thank you so much!